# Layout fixed width, full height with fixed footer, full width

Tags: css, layout, overlap

I could use some help on a layout. This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Layout fixed width, full height with fixed footer, full width]

Here are the specs:

- header has fixed height
- footer is always at the bottom and has full width (100%)
- content has fixed width
- content basically has full height minus the footer, but overlaps the footer by exactly 20px

This of course must work when the content is both shorter and longer than the viewport.
I've been playing around with this for a few hours and I just can't get it to fulfill all the features.

I created a fiddle for it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Sq4Pk/6/

The problems with this solution are currently:

- the shorter the viewport gets, the more the content overlaps the footer (must be exactly 20px)
- the content part does not fill the viewport

Is this even possible? Can somebody help me out with this?

I've tried these solutions and variations thereof but both are slightly different from my usecase:

- http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/examples/csslayout1.html
- http://www.cssstickyfooter.com

Thanks a lot for any help!

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a fiddle with a possible workaround, inserting two extra divs in the footer to fake the overlay.

One annoying downside: in Chrome the highest div (to mask the dropshadow) seems to shift 1px upon resize. FF + IE are fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/Sq4Pk/3/

EDIT: found a fix for the pixel shift in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/Sq4Pk/4/

EDIT2: or if it's an option to use jQuery, the result is even slightly better: http://jsfiddle.net/Sq4Pk/5/

Comment: Thanks for your response! The problem is, #content shouldn't scroll, it should grow with the content and fill the viewport in every case. Any ideas on this?

Comment: That would just hide the content instead of extending #content to fit everything though.

Comment: sorry, misunderstood. in that case, remove the height from #content, and remove the absolute positioning from #footer http://jsfiddle.net/Sq4Pk/9/ (this is again the non-jQuery solution)

Comment: Thanks. nr. 9 is looking pretty good, but the footer isn't at the bottom when the content is shorter than the viewport.

Comment: Added min-height:80% to #content

Comment: That did it! I was already losing hope. Thank you so much for your time! I would buy you a beer now if I could :)